# Compression of randomly ordered non-repeating incremental integers

Tags: python, algorithm, math, set, compression

I have a set of 100 integers from 0-99 in random order. Each number in the range occurs exactly once. I am looking for the most effective lossless compression algorithm to compress this data while maintaining the ability to decompress it efficiently?

I know that compressing random numbers is theoretically not possible, but I'm wondering if it's possible for this case since each number only appears once and you basically just need to compress the order of the numbers somehow... Please don't be harsh, I'm not an expert in this field. Also, any tips for python implementations would be greatly appreciated! :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there _any_ non-randomness that could be exploited? If not, then there is no answer I'm afraid...

Comment: Also, the topic says "incremental integers", but the question says "in random order". So, which is it?

Comment: @user2722968 I have a set of integers from 0-99. Each number appears exactly once, so it's somehow incremental, but they're in random order.

Comment: @user2722968 There is a small probability that numbers that are "close" to each other will also appear in "groups" in the set, but I don't think it's significant.

Comment: If every number appears exactly once then you have a permutation on 100 elements. These permutations can be indexed with an index from 1 to 100! and back again. So you compress to an integer up to approx. 9.33 *10^157. You need at least 525 bits.

Comment: How large is the set? If it's "small", you may have the option of pre-calculating a minimal perfect hash function and only store that hash. Otherwise: The integers only take 7 bit to represent, so you can group 7 bytes and store one number in the otherwise unused bit. If they are "close", you can delta-encode the sequence to reduce the number of 1-bits, which is beneficial for huffman coding.

Comment: What would you consider "efficiently"?

Comment: @user2722968 Oops, sorry, I forgot to mention... There are exactly 100 integers.

Comment: @KellyBundy Lossless and as fast as possible, preferably under 5 seconds.

Comment: A naive compression to 700 bits is possible by just putting each number in 7 bits.

Comment: @George, as the previous comment said, there are `100! = 11^157` permutations of that set, so there is no way to pre-compute that. I'd try delta-encoding the sequence, then a 7/8th encoding where you use the otherwise unused top-bit to encode one number for every seven bytes. There isn't much to be gained here, probably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the permutation index as the compression result, usually compresses to 66 bytes and takes less than a millisecond:

```
from random import shuffle
from more_itertools import permutation_index, nth_permutation

n = 100
r = range(n)

for _ in range(3):
    a = list(r)
    shuffle(a)
    
    i = permutation_index(a, r)
    compressed = i.to_bytes(-(i.bit_length() // -8), 'big')
    decompressed = list(nth_permutation(r, n, int.from_bytes(compressed, 'big')))
    print(len(compressed), decompressed == a)
```

Should usually output (compressed bytes size and whether it was correct, three random attempts):

```
66 True
66 True
66 True
```

For n=10000, it usually compresses to 14808 bytes and still takes less than a second.

Comment: I was going to suggest compressing the `compressed` result with `zstd`, but it adds 9-10 bytes, and of course that makes sense given that the vast majority of random large integers shouldn't be compressible.

Comment: @JasonS Yeah, that might help if `to_bytes` encoded suboptimally, but it doesn't.

Comment: Nah, `to_bytes` just takes an integer and expresses it as bytes. The entropy of a random integer is its length in bits.